# Use index of array to find the corresponding index in a filtered version of that array

Tags: javascript

Given the following array:

`const arr = ["a", "c", "b", "c", "b"]`

And given an index of `4`, how can we return the index of the corresponding element in `["b", "b"]`? In this example, the answer is `1`.

More generally, how can we use the index of `arr` to find the corresponding index of `b` in `arr2` where `const arr2 = arr.filter(item => item === "b")`?

### Examples:

`["a", "c", "b", "c", "b"][4]` corresponds to `["b", "b"][1]`

`["a", "c", "b", "c", "b", "b"][4]` corresponds to `["b", "b", "b"][1]`

### Inputs and expected outputs

```
function getCorrespondingIndexInFilteredArray(array, index, filterValue) {...}

getCorrespondingIndexInFilteredArray(["a", "c", "b", "c", "b"], 4, "b") // 1
getCorrespondingIndexInFilteredArray(["a", "c", "b", "c", "b", "b"], 4, "b") // 1
getCorrespondingIndexInFilteredArray(["b", "b"], 0, "b") // 0
getCorrespondingIndexInFilteredArray(["b", "b"], 1, "b") // 1
getCorrespondingIndexInFilteredArray(["a", "a"], 0, "b") // either 0 or -1 is alright here
```

Comment: The answer of your first question will be a `Boolean`. And answer of second question will be `Number`? Please be more clear. What is input and what is expected output

Comment: It's unclear. Can you provide a signature of the function you're trying to build? Is `b` part of the input? Because it seems you will provide the index and you want to get the item + it's count till that index?

Comment: Good points, let me clarify the question.

Comment: _"...return the index...the answer is `2`."_ - Not possible because the array only has to elements.

Comment: ```const arr2 = arr.findIndex(item => item === 'b'); console.log(arr2) // 1``` use findIndex for finding index of the array!

Comment: @BloodyLogic, hmm, that returns the same answer in this case but it's not what I'm looking for. I'll clarify the question more.

Comment: @charlietfl yes, that's correct. `["a", "c", "b", "c", "b"][4]` corresponds to `["b", "b"][1]`

Comment: @charlietfl No, since `["a", "c", "b", "c", "b", "b"][4]` corresponds to `["b", "b", "b"][1]`

Comment: @charlietfl the first version of the question was more "clear" on that. `4` is the index of the "second" `b` in the array. TO is looking for the index of the "second" `b` in `["b", "b"]`.

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah You realize yourself that your question is absolutely not unambiguous or clearly understandable, right? Add some test cases (input and expected output) - in the question itself.

Comment: @Andreas, yes, I am realizing this. I'll rephrase the question. In the meantime, it seems that this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57313134/1911755 is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `slice()` upto the given index and then get the count of elements which are equal to element at given index.

```js
const arr = ["a", "b", "c", "b"]
const other = (arr, ind) => {
  return arr.slice(0,ind).reduce((ac, a) => a === arr[ind] ? ac + 1: ac, 0);
}
console.log(other(arr,3))
console.log(other(arr,1))
```

Comment: The problem here is that I'm looking to get the _corresponding_ "b" in `arr = ["a", "b", "c", "b"]` and I don't think this approach can guarantee that the it's always the corresponding element, just one that has the same value.

Comment: *And given an index of 4, how can we return the index of the corresponding element in ["b", "b"]? In this example, the answer is 1.*  `->` your approach returns `-1`

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah I have updated. Please check it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `counter` object and a `for` loop

```js
function customIndex(arr, index) {
  const counter = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    counter[arr[i]] = counter[arr[i]] + 1 || 0;
    if (index === i)
      return counter[arr[i]]
  }
  return 'index out of bound'
}

console.log(customIndex(["a", "b", "c", "b"], 3))

console.log(customIndex(["a", "a", "b", "a"], 3))
console.log(customIndex(["a", "a", "b", "a"], 1))
```

You could [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the array to get the items which match `arr[index]` but only until `index`. (This will not short circuit like this first snippet)

```js
const customIndex = (arr, index) => 
  arr.filter((n, i) => n === arr[index] && i <= index).length - 1

console.log(customIndex(["a", "b", "c", "b"], 3))
console.log(customIndex(["a", "a", "b", "a"], 3))
console.log(customIndex(["a", "a", "b", "a"], 1))
```

Comment: @adiga I'm not sure what `arr` is in Andreas' exmaple but your solution is correct as far as I can tell.

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah I have added a shorter `filter` option (This is not as efficient as the first snippet if the array is big)